# grunt serve not working

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

Hi looking for some help. I have installed

1. node.js
2. yeoman
   3.angular
3. npm install -g generator-webapp

when I go to test it on server using grunt serve, I get this response

-bash: grunt: command not found

don't know what i'm doing wrong

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: Did you install grunt?

Comment: yeah clive have done.

Comment: hm? did You install npm install -g grunt-cli ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to install the command line utility for Grunt.

`npm install -g grunt-cli`

You might need to run it with sudo

Answer (score 1):

Installing npm install grunt is not enough. It just installs local grunt. You also need grunt-cli installed to use grunt command. To do that, input:

```
npm install -g grunt-cli
```

Comment: Thanks Clive and Jarema d'oh just realised my mistake. working now however it is throwing an error" Cannot find where you keep your Bower packages."

Comment: and this: https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack/issues/230

Did You do `npm install` and `bower install` in that app folder?

Comment: Yeah Jarema done both. Bower JSON is in my directory Gruntfile.js app  bower.json node_modules package.json test

Comment: I have no clue then. check links. otherwise - ask new question, as this is  a different thing :).

Answer (score 0):

Sorted Thanks Folks for all the help

Solution

1) npm install -g bower
2) in the file app I was using install bower